# How to implement Retry logic in RabbitMQ?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-retry, retrypolicy

In my project I'm setting `SimpleRetryPolicy` to add custom exception and `RetryOperationsInterceptor` which is consuming this policy.

```
@Bean
    public SimpleRetryPolicy rejectionRetryPolicy() {
        Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> exceptionsMap = new HashMap<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean>();
        exceptionsMap.put(DoNotRetryException.class, false);//not retriable
        exceptionsMap.put(RetryException.class, true); //retriable
        return new SimpleRetryPolicy(3, exceptionsMap, true);
    }

    @Bean
    RetryOperationsInterceptor interceptor() {
        return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
                .retryPolicy(rejectionRetryPolicy())
                .backOffOptions(2000L, 2, 3000L)
                .recoverer(
                        new RepublishMessageRecoverer(rabbitTemplate(), "dlExchange", "dlRoutingKey"))
                .build();
    }
```

But with these configurations retry is not working for both RetryException and DoNotRetryException, where I want RetryException to be retried finite number of time and DoNotRetryException to send to DLQ

Please help with the issue, I'm attaching repo link if in case of need.

https://github.com/aviralnimbekar/RabbitMQ/tree/main/src

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `GlobalErrorHandler` does its logic before the retry happens and you override there an exception with the `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`. And looks like you do there a publish to DLX. Consider to move your `GlobalErrorHandler` logic to a more general `ErrorHandler` for the `factory.setErrorHandler();` instead.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#exception-handling

**UPDATE**

After removing `errorHandler = "globalErrorHandler"` from your `@RabbitListener`, I got this in logs:

```
2022-08-03 16:02:08.093  INFO 16896 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.t.r.producer.RabbitMQProducer          : Message sent -> retry
2022-08-03 16:02:08.095  INFO 16896 --- [ntContainer#0-1] c.t.r.consumer.RabbitMQConsumer          : Retrying message...
2022-08-03 16:02:10.096  INFO 16896 --- [ntContainer#0-1] c.t.r.consumer.RabbitMQConsumer          : Retrying message...
2022-08-03 16:02:13.099  INFO 16896 --- [ntContainer#0-1] c.t.r.consumer.RabbitMQConsumer          : Retrying message...
2022-08-03 16:02:13.100  WARN 16896 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.retry.RepublishMessageRecoverer  : Republishing failed message to exchange 'dlExchange' with routing key dlRoutingKey
2022-08-03 16:02:17.736  INFO 16896 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.t.r.producer.RabbitMQProducer          : Message sent -> 1231231
2022-08-03 16:02:17.738  INFO 16896 --- [ntContainer#0-1] c.t.r.consumer.RabbitMQConsumer          : sending into dlq...
2022-08-03 16:02:17.739  WARN 16896 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.retry.RepublishMessageRecoverer  : Republishing failed message to exchange 'dlExchange' with routing key dlRoutingKey
```

Which definitely reflects your original requirements.

Comment: I tried setting `ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler` into `factory.setErrorHandler();` with `CustomFatalExceptionStrategy` to add my list of fatal exception i.e.  `DoNotRetryException` as per the blog. Also had to eliminate`GlobalErrorHandler`. Now it is retying for all type of exception.

Comment: Please, see an UPDATE in my answer.